# Domains over which a differential equation is defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of $x'=x^2$ and the domain that each solution is defined. Here, $x'=dx/dt$. Give an example of a differential equation that has a solution satisfying $x(0)=0$ and is only defined for $-1<t<1$.

I determined that the general solution of the differential equation was $x=-{1 \over t+C}$ and then I think my restricted domain is $t\neq-C$ where C is an arbitrary constant. I am not sure how to find a differential equation that satisfies $x(0)=0$ and is only defined for $-1<t<1$.

Comment: You have it the wrong way around. The constant $C$ is determined by the initial condition. The existence/uniqueness theorem implies that the equation with the initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$ has a solution for any $(t_0,x_0)$ in $some$ interval containing $t_0,$ because $\partial x^2/\partial x=2x$ is continuous everywhere (in $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: @matematleta I'm not sure if I quite understand what you are saying. Do I need to consider a different restricted domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must consider a differentiable function that is defined only on $(-1,1)$ and such that $x(0)=0$.

An example can be $x(t)=tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)$, that satisfies the Cauchy problem

$x’=\frac{\pi}{2}(1+x^2)$

$x(0)=0$